# Gnuplot console window doesn't open when script is called

Tags: gnuplot

I have a problem with gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8 (but previous patchlevels had the same issue) on Windows 10: When executing a script file (from the explorer by double-clickung on the `.plt` file), the plot window opens, but I cannot get the console window to open (as it used to do with space bar on 4.6). I'm using the `wxt` terminal, but it's the same with `qt`. Is there a way to get the console window?

Bonus question: In case there is an error in the script, how do I get gnuplot to open the console window and siplay the error message instead of immedately shutting down again?

Comment: how do you execute your script? From the Windows Command prompt?

Comment: @theozh: by double-clickign on the file (I have updated the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are double clicking on the file and gnuplot starts, then Windows has some association with this filetype to open these files. I don't know what this is in your case. Maybe `gnuplot.exe`?

Why not starting `wgnuplot.exe` to open the gnuplot console and typing `load "myScript.gp"` or eventually using the full path of your script?
And if you modified something in your script press the "Arrow-up-key" and "Enter" and run the script again.

What you can find in the manual on page 45:

> If gnuplot was built with configuration option `-enable-raise-console`,
>   then typing  in the plot window raises gnuplot's command
>   window.

Apparently, your and my version were not built with this option.

Comment: (a) The `.plt`extension is associated with `wgnuplot.exe`.(B) Of course I can start gnuplot directly, but then I have to manually change the directory.

Comment: well, but this means if you build it yourself you can include this option ;-)

Comment: Windows gnuplot installer [associates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497889/is-there-a-standard-file-extension-for-gnuplot-files/75743206#75743206) ```.gp```, ```.gpl``` and  ```.plt``` with ```wgnuplot.exe```. Double clicking a script file (bearing one of these extensions) does call wgnuplot and draws the plot, however, the wgnuplots console does not open.